# Authenticate Angular Application to Web Api with Existing SSO using Ping Federate

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1, pingfederate

We have an existing SSO application with a login form that authenticates to ping federate.

I am trying to use this same SSO mechanism with angular cli 11.

I am to the point where I have the open token returned from Pingfederate.  What I am trying to do no us set up my ASP.NET core application to accept this token, validate it, and grant me access to the claims within.

In an older MVC application, this token is decrypted using an opentoken library with what looks like just a password.

How do I configure my .net core 3.1 application to accept and validate this open token?

Here's what I have so far:

```
services.AddAuthentication()
            .AddOAuth("urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:saml2-bearer", opt =>
            {
                opt.ClientId = Configuration["PingOpenToken:ClientId"];
                opt.ClientSecret = Configuration["PingOpenToken:ClientSecret"];
            });
```

Where client secret is the same password we are using to decrypt tokens.  I do not know what should be in the Client Id value.

The `urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:saml2-bearer` came from [This ping documentation](https://docs.pingidentity.com/bundle/pingfederate-93/page/mmn1564002963991.html)

I am assuming I am going to place the open token that I have as in the Authorization header as `bearer {token}`.

And just to validate my pingfederate configuration and see if I need to turn anything else on, under my protocol settings, I have:

- Enable OAuth 2.0 Authorization Server: false
- IdP SAML 2.0 Support: true
- SP SAML 2.0 Support: true

If I need to turn on oAuth 2.0, I would have no idea how to configure it.

Comment: MUST you use the OpenToken adapter? Or, can you work with your PF admin to use  the Agentless adapter? The Agentless is easier, the browser brings you a reference, your application sends that reference and the application's secret to PF, and you get a JSON of the attribute map back... Way simpler, and less likely to be disrupted in the future.

Comment: Unfortunately, the previous admin was let go, so I'm forced to figure this out on my own.  All the older sites use this open token method through our SSO application, and it seems our PF version is old enough that the only offering we have is open token.  We have some library that appears to have been written by PF years ago that is used to read and write tokens, but it's written in 4.0 and is not compatible with core.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After having a call with a couple people over at PingFederate, I figured out how to configure and use PF oauth instead of utilizing their opentoken implementation.

The gist is that the user is sent to SSO and when they come back to my angular app, they hit a url with a token.  Then, I do an API call back to PF with the token to get their oauth token.

Then in my API, I have a dual configuration for azure ad service principal and PF like this:

```
services.AddAuthentication()
            .AddJwtBearer(ApiConstants.AuthenticationSchemes.AzureBearerToken, opt =>
            {
                opt.Audience = Configuration["AzureAd:ResourceId"];
                opt.Authority = $"{Configuration["AzureAd:Instance"]}{Configuration["AzureAd:TenantId"]}";
                opt.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidateAudience = true,
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = false
                };
            })
            .AddJwtBearer(ApiConstants.AuthenticationSchemes.PingBearerToken, opt =>
            {
                opt.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidateAudience = true,
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    ValidIssuer = Configuration["PingFederate:JwtIssuer"],
                    ValidAudience = Configuration["PingFederate:JwtAudience"],
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["PingFederate:JwtSymmetricKey"]))
                };
            });

        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                .AddAuthenticationSchemes(ApiConstants.AuthenticationSchemes.PingBearerToken, 
                    ApiConstants.AuthenticationSchemes.AzureBearerToken)
                .Build();
        });
```

My two constants values are "azure" and "ping".